# How can I get the UNC path of a file that is on a mapped network drive

Tags: networking, windows-shell

.NET 4.0 and this is a shell extension
when a file is selected my context menu handler get the mapped drive path but I need the UNC path for reasons too long to explain. Is there a way to get the UNC path from a mapped drive. Alternatively can I enumerate all mapped drives and what they map to so that based on the drive letter I can look up this information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WNetGetConnection()` function to convert from a mapped drive letter to the UNC path.

I can't help you with .NET sorry (which you [should be careful about writing shell extensions using](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx)) but in C++,

```
LPCWSTR pszPath = L"M:\\"; // mapped drive
if (GetDriveType(pszPath) == DRIVE_REMOTE)
{
    // WNetGetConnection needs drive letter WITHOUT trailing backslash
    wchar_t wchDrive[3] = { pszPath[0], pszPath[1], L'\0' };
    wchar_t wchUNC[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwLength = _countof(wchUNC);
    if (WNetGetConnection(wchDrive, wchUNC, &dwLength) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        // do something with wchUNC
    }
}
```